# Keyboard shortcuts not working on website, because of autostart of QUICK FIND in FIREFOX 6.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I am implementing keyboard shortcuts on a website, these shortcuts are similar to Gmail. The problem I am facing with Firefox 6.0 is that, the quick find starts immediately as soon as I type any letter. If I open Gmail, the quick find only opens when I press apostrophe (').

Because of this, none of the keyboard shortcuts works on the website. It is working fine on all the other browsers and other versions of Firefox.

Should I use `event.preventDefault()` for each character. I don't want to do that, is there any other work around?

Comment: You should post a code snippet where you handle keyboard events.

Comment: I think "no" is the correct answer - if you want to prevent the default action then `event.preventDefault()` is exactly what you should use.

Answer (score 3):

Using `event.preventDefault()` on each key event whose default action you want to prevent is *exactly* the right thing to do here.  Why do you not want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without looking at your code, but it seems that you are intercepting the `keypress` event, when you should be intercepting the `keydown` event. If you use `event.preventDefault()` on the `keydown` event, it should prevent the default browser behaviour connected to that key.